# odoo interface display incorrectly

Tags: odoo-10

I have starting to learn odoo recently and using odoo:10.0. but I have a problem with odoo interface where it display almost nothing at all. Here are my screenshots :

My odoo before sign in:

[image: My odoo before sign in]

My odoo after sign in:

[image: My odoo after sign in]

Comment: Try after clearing the browser cookies and cache memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed myself to fix the problem.
My problem is that there is an error in js where this line:

```
odoo.define('web.csrt', function(required) {
 var token = " some_long_number";
 required('web.core').csrt_token = token;
 required('qweb').default_dict.csrt_token = token;
}
```

`Uncaught ReferencesError: odoo is not defined`

First I install odoo to another device, then I access my localhost:8069 with that device by using local IP (192.168.x.x:8069)

After the the website in that device loads correctly, my original device starts to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

how did you install odoo? this is usually caused by improper rendering of CSS,

https://github.com/mpdevilleres/odoo-vagrant-dev/blob/master/bootstrap.sh

this might help you setup your development environment.

Comment: I install it by using docker. First I use `docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo --name db postgres:9.4` then I use `docker run -v /path/to/addons:/mnt/extra-addons -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo`

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

Then restart `odoo server` try again.

**Note:** Experience same problem, try on `incognito browser`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thank for the answer, but since I install odoo10 by docker, sudo command seem not work